# How do I store my music collection in their new(-ish) location on macOS?

Tags: macos, itunes, music

When I check the size of my music collection (Ventura; Music 1.3)

```
$ du -hs ~/Music/iTunes 
 131G   /Users/sam/Music/iTunes
$ du -hs ~/Music/Music 
 61M    /Users/sam/Music/Music
```

I see that all the music files remain where `iTunes` stored them.

How do I store my music collection in their new location?

Context: I'm migrating (manually) to a new Macbook Pro,
and I'd now like to move the collection to an external disk.
In my attempts so far the files are referenced at their old address under `iTunes`.

Comment: Have a look at both answers on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293764/move-external-itunes-library-files-to-different-location-without-losing-metadata I haven't actually done this in a long time, so I don't know which parts are still relevant. Make copies before you play with anything.